# How to save that my button has already been tapped in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code that, when tapped it will add the number of likes to a post, it will only allow the user to tap it once, works well but when I reload the app I can like it again, been trying to workout the best way to save that it has been tapped already. I have added the button state as false:
@State var buttonTapped = false

```
        Button(action:
                       
                            {
                                
                                self.buttonTapped.toggle() //only allow one tap
                                
                                let like = Int.init(post.likes)!
                                ref.collection("Posts").document(post.id).updateData(["likes": "\(like
    + 1)"]) { (err) in
                                
                                if err != nil{
                                    
                                    print((err!.localizedDescription))
                                    return
                                }
                               // postData.getAllPosts()
                                print("updated...")
                                    
                            
                            }
                                
                            }
                        
                    ) {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "flame")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        
        
                    }.disabled(buttonTapped)
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your code doesn't look well-formatted.

Comment: As far as I understood it is per-posts which there are many, so you need to store that state in `Post` model.

Comment: apologies, I can never workout how to get it formatted correctly, I'm gonna have to resort to typing each line instead of copy and pasting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UserDefaults to store the value

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var buttonTapped : Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "buttonTapped")
    var body : some View {

        Button(action: {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "buttonTapped")
            buttonTapped.toggle()            
        }) {
                        
            Image(systemName: "flame")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        }.disabled(buttonTapped)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that worked perfect, sorry for my really bad formatting